# How do you add a widget to a form field in init in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Basically, I want to change a form field's widget in the init function. First of all, here is the form:

```
class ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].choices = DATE_CHOICES

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = (
            'date',
         )
         widgets = {'date': SelectDateWidget()}
```

However, the widget `SelectDateWidget()` didn't seem to work for some reason. So, I want to instead add this widget to the init function so that the widget would be reflected on the form. However, this is just my thought. If adding this widget to the init function will not work, could you please give me some way to use this widget for the `date` field? Thank you, and please leave me any questions you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the date is a `DateField`, then you can add the `SelectDateWidget` like this :

```
class ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(empty_label=("Choose Year", "Choose Month", "Choose Day"),))

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = (
            'date',
        )
```

Now if you want to add some defined choices then follow [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget) for more details.

[The doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets) is also good to read.

**NB :** You not have to override the`__init__` method for that.